MS Access: "The active content in this file is blocked"
I am getting the "The active content in this file is blocked" error from MS Access despite the following updates as suggested by various posts on this site and others.  Any additional suggestions would be appreciated.
In Internet Properties:

Where the file is located has been added to the list of Trusted Sites.

In MS Access Trust Center Settings:

Where the file is located has been added to the list of Trusted Locations
In Trusted Documents, the Allow documents on a network to be trusted box is checked.
In Macro Settings, the Enable all macros is selected.


Check the file properties in case the file is blocked - there should be an "Unblock" checkbox if that's the case.

I have seen a screenshot with that checkbox posted in responses to other similar questions, but that is not available.

Figured out the answer late yesterday (20-Jun).
TLDR Answer:
Use a named location (\\servername\folder\...), not an IP address (\\1.2.3.4\folder\...)
Full Answer:
I went to add the IP Address to the list of trusted sites in addition to the named location that was already in the list.  Access denied it saying that

The path you have entered cannot be used as a Trusted Location for security reasons. Choose another location or a specific folder.

This led me to try copying the file from the network location to the user's desktop and it worked fine.  Then I looked at the shortcut and noticed it's listed location was \\1.2.3.4\folder\... and changed it to \\servername\folder\....  Once I did that the program was able to launch without a problem.
